# 502 Error by executing the train function of my machine learning code

Tags: php, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have created machine learning code for a school assignment but every time I execute the train function I get a 502: Bad Gateway error and I don't know how to solve it. I also don't know where this error comes from.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");

$sql = "SELECT rate, type, level FROM opinions, nameCable WHERE opinions.cableNameID = nameCable.cableNameID";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Prepare the dataset
$dataset = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Prepare the features and target variables
    $features = [
        $row['type'],
        $row['level']
    ];
    $target = $row['rate'];

    // Add the example to the dataset
    $dataset[] = [$features, $target];
}

// Split the dataset into training and testing sets
$trainRatio = 0.8;
$trainSize = (int) (count($dataset) * $trainRatio);
$trainSet = array_slice($dataset, 0, $trainSize);
$testSet = array_slice($dataset, $trainSize);

// Define the linear regression model
class LinearRegression
{
    private $weights;

    public function train($trainSet)
    {
        $X = [];
        $y = [];

        foreach ($trainSet as [$features, $target]) {
            $X[] = $features;
            $y[] = $target;
        }

        $X = array_map(function ($row) {
            array_unshift($row, 1); // Add a bias term
            return $row;
        }, $X);

        $X = array_map(null, ...$X); // Transpose the matrix

        $XtX = self::matrixMultiply(self::matrixTranspose($X), $X);
        $Xty = self::matrixMultiply(self::matrixTranspose($X), $y);

        $this->weights = self::matrixMultiply(self::matrixInverse($XtX), $Xty);
    }

    public function predict($features)
    {
        array_unshift($features, 1); // Add a bias term
        return self::matrixMultiply($features, $this->weights);
    }

    private static function matrixTranspose($matrix)
    {
        return array_map(null, ...$matrix);
    }

    private static function matrixMultiply($matrix1, $matrix2)
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach ($matrix1 as $row) {
            $resultRow = [];

            foreach ($matrix2[0] as $j => $col) {
                $resultCol = 0;

                foreach ($row as $i => $element) {
                    $resultCol += $element * $matrix2[$i][$j];
                }

                $resultRow[] = $resultCol;
            }

            $result[] = $resultRow;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private static function matrixInverse($matrix)
    {
        $n = count($matrix);
        $augmented = array_map(function ($row) {
            return array_merge($row, array_fill(0, count($row), 0));
        }, $matrix);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $augmented[$i][$i + $n] = 1;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $pivot = $augmented[$i][$i];

            for ($j = $i; $j < $n * 2; $j++) {
                $augmented[$i][$j] /= $pivot;
            }

            for ($k = 0; $k < $n; $k++) {
                if ($k !== $i) {
                    $factor = $augmented[$k][$i];

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $n * 2; $j++) {
                        $augmented[$k][$j] -= $factor * $augmented[$i][$j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return array_map(function ($row) use ($n) {
            return array_slice($row, $n);
        }, $augmented);
    }
}

// Train the linear regression model
$lr = new LinearRegression();
$lr->train($trainSet);  this is the problem

// Evaluate the model on the test set
$totalError = 0;
$totalPredictions = count($testSet);

foreach ($testSet as [$features, $target]) {
    $prediction = $lr->predict($features);
    $error = array_map(function ($t, $p) {
        return $t - $p;
    }, $target, $prediction);
    $totalError += array_sum(array_map('abs', $error));
}

$averageError = $totalError / $totalPredictions;

// Print the average error of the model
echo "Average Error: " . $averageError;

?>
```

Can please someone help me how to solve this problem? I am really sure this is the row it goes wrong at. When I comment that row and the rest of the code below that row it doesn't give an error.

Comment: Since training usually take a while, my first guess is that the server is timing out. My second guess is that you are running out of memory for the PHP process.